# How to forbid NULL value for function pointer parameter

Tags: c++

I have a function:

```
void foo(int parm11, pointer to function) {…}
```

and I would like to forbid calling it with the `NULL` value for the second parameter. In other words I want to get an error message from the compiler at the following C++ source line:

```
foo(5, NULL);
```

Comment: Consider passing by reference instead.

Comment: You can't get the compiler to check the value of an argument, only its type.

Comment: You can use `assert()` for runtime checking during debug mode.

Comment: @Galik: Why only during debug mode? Just don't define `NDEBUG` in the translation unit which implements `foo`.

Comment: @ChristianHackl often release builds will define `NDEBUG` globally using a command line option.

Comment: @immibis: Yes, and I consider this a very questionable practice which produces unreliable and dangerous production software.

Comment: @ChristianHackl yes, well, other people don't, and the fact is that `assert` is often only enabled in debug builds.

Comment: @ChristianHackl: Seems like any defect you see would be in the specification of `assert()`.  Anyway, this isn't productive because OP is asking for a compile-time check.

Comment: @ChristianHackl Because `if` statements slow code down. `assert` lets you do severe checks at debug time without slowing the release code.

Comment: @BenVoigt: What part of the specification are you referring to, exactly? The standard calls `assert` "a macro for documenting C++ program assertions", and `NDEBUG` "a mechanism for disabling the assertion checks".

Comment: @Galik: Removing error checks from production code because they *may* be slow looks like premature optimisation to me.

Comment: @ChristianHackl: Yes that part.  You are saying that assertion checks should never be disabled, which conflicts with the design providing a kill switch.

Comment: @ChristianHackl You should put asserts in far more places than you would normal runtime checks. If you want a check in production code, use `if() throw exception();` not `assert`.

Comment: @BenVoigt: No, I merely disagree with the notion that the switch should be used globally for production code.

Comment: @Galik: Why throw an exception if I want the application to terminate immediately? Exceptions only make sense if you catch them somewhere to handle them. How do you handle a wrong `NULL` argument caused by a bug in the source code?

Comment: @ChristianHackl I'm not sure why anyone would want production code to terminate without even telling the user something bad happened and saving data tbh.

Comment: @Galik: Because wrong source code causes strange things and undefined behaviour which may be far worse than a crash. For example, the application could continue running and corrupt files, write wrong data to sockets, break security barriers or send wrong queries to databases. Much better to kill it off immediately and have the application process be restarted automatically in some way.

Comment: @ChristianHackl So what is wrong with throwing an exception and then ending? The point is you can put `assertions` in many more places than you would put normal critical runtime checks because they have no cost, they are free and you can be liberal with them.

Comment: @Galik: The biggest problem with throwing an exception is that anyone can catch it with `catch (...)` and keep the application process from dying. Another problem is that unwanted things may happen during stack unwinding (e.g. corrupt data may be automatically written somewhere because a buffer is flushed in a destructor). Exceptions are designed behaviour, assertions are for bugs in the code.

Comment: @ChristianHackl You can terminate without using `assert` if that is what you want to do.  My main point is that `assert` is designed with a specific engineering purpose in mind. If you want production checks then put explicit production code in to express them. It is better not to subvert `assert` from its designed purpose.

Comment: @Galik: Well, of course I can just terminate without `assert`. But why should I if `assert` does precisely what I want to do? As for `assert`'s designed purpose, the standard does not say anything about debug and release builds. That `assert` is enabled by default and that the switch to disable it allows you to control translation units individually does not indicate to me that you should just globally turn off the mechanism.

Comment: @ChristianHackl My last comment on this. If you want code to appear in the product in both debug **and** release builds then why would you make its inclusion ***conditional*** based on a macro? That sounds a little dangerous to me. If code is intended to *always* be present it just doesn't feel correct to use a conditional inclusion mechanism. Better to use *unconditional* code.

Comment: @Galik: Because then I *can* turn it off individually for a compilation unit when and *if* profiling shows it's necessary to meet certain non-functional requirements of the software. I could use my own macros for that and basically duplicate `assert` and `NDEBUG` with different names, or I can just use what the standard library gives me.

Answer (score 11):

You can catch an explicit [`nullptr`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/nullptr) (and anything convertible to a null pointer constant), since it has its own type:

```
void foo(int, pfunc_type); // Your function
void foo(int, std::nullptr_t) = delete; // The "bad" overload
```

Of course, a determined user can still pass a null function pointer, they just can't do it by directly specifying a null pointer constant for the argument.

It may be preferable to reconsider pointers, and just take function references, as [AlexD recommended](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48613116/how-to-forbid-null-value-for-pointer-parameter-of-function#comment84222847_48613116).

Comment: For the `NULL` thing, you could likewise add a deleted overload taking `int` (and probably also one taking `long`).

Comment: @Angew - Maybe one taking `decltype(NULL)`? Would save on guessing

Comment: @StoryTeller: Using `decltype(NULL)` has one problem, though - it means that the function can now only be used if `NULL` is actually defined.

Comment: @ChristianHackl - Well, you need `cstddef` for both `nullptr_t` and `NULL`. I omitted it for brevity, but will add in

Comment: @StoryTeller: True. But you don't need `std::nullptr_t`, you can cheat by using `void foo(int, decltype(nullptr)) = delete;` without including any standard header.

Comment: You don't need an extra overload to catch NULL, null literal constants have an implicit conversion to `nullptr_t`, the first suggestion already covers `nullptr`, `0`, `0ULL`, and `NULL`

Comment: @BenVoigt - Fancy that. My mind is blown, since I never considered trying anything other than `nullptr` for that use-case. Thank you.